# How to run a multiline script in truffle console?

Tags: truffle

I'm following [truffle tutorial](http://truffleframework.com/docs/getting_started/contracts#making-a-transaction) to interact with a deployed contract and have a naive question. How do I run this block of multiline scripts in `truffle(development)>` without collapsing it into a single line?

```
var account_one = "0x1234..."; // an address
var account_two = "0xabcd..."; // another address

var meta;
MetaCoin.deployed().then(function(instance) {
  meta = instance;
  return meta.sendCoin(account_two, 10, {from: account_one});
}).then(function(result) {
  // If this callback is called, the transaction was successfully processed.
  alert("Transaction successful!")
}).catch(function(e) {
  // There was an error! Handle it.
})
```

Comment: I haven't used truffle myself, but in Node.js, you could just paste this in (or type it by hand), and the newlines wouldn't be a problem. Does the truffle console not work the same way?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. It throws `SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input` at `MetaCoin.deployed().then(function(instance) {`.

Comment: Disappointing! I'm sure someone will come along with a helpful answer. :-) Good luck!

Comment: Are you looking for a particular solution with a console or you just need a solution to run this code? Sorry, I just need to clarify.

Comment: @RomanFrolov I'm looking for a generic solution to run multiline code under truffle console mode.

Comment: You need to save your js code in some file and then use `exec ./somefile.js` from console. Before this you will need to use `migrate` to deploy your contracts to a blockchain, which you can run with Ganache or truffle develop.

Comment: If this is your first truffle tutorial, let me suggest [this one](http://truffleframework.com/tutorials/pet-shop). Just because it will cover every topic in the development. As for tutorial that you are following you may need to complete the code to actually run it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can simply `require` the file you want to run, just like how you would in a node application:

```
$ echo "console.log('hello')" > myfile.js
$ truffle console
truffle(development)> require('./myfile.js')
hello
```

However, the deployed contract won't be available but truffle does offer the `exec` command which injects a web3 provider. You'd just have to create the contract instance.

Example `myfile.js`

```
const artifacts = require('./build/contracts/MyContract.json')
const contract = require('truffle-contract')
const MyContract = contract(artifacts);
MyContract.setProvider(web3.currentProvider);

MyContract.deployed()
.then(function(instance) {
  console.log(instance.address)
})
.catch(function(error) {
  console.error(error)
})
```

Then run in console:

```
$ truffle console
truffle(development)> exec ./myfile.js
0x6e153f03845fc132d73cb03c3f1d1b6c13d715fc
```

Comment: Your example works. But as soon as I use `MetaCoin` in `myfile.js`, it complains `ReferenceError: MetaCoin is not defined`.

Comment: @sinoTrinity are you sure you compiled it and see the artifacts in build/contracts/MetaCoin.json? The paths are relative as well so make sure your file is in the correct directory.

Comment: Works after I install `truffle-contract`.

Comment: When running it with `exec` the script always gets stuck: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/58337/truffle-exec-gets-stuck
maybe you can help me, thx?

Answer (score 3):

Truffle-Contract is now deprecated:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/truffle-contract

We should be using now:
@truffle/contract
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@truffle/contract

Also as of today this works on truffle console:

```
const CakeToken = artifacts.require("./CakeToken.sol")

module.exports = async function(callback) {
    const cakeToken = await CakeToken.deployed()
    console.log(cakeToken.address)
}
```