# Truffle Exec Gets Stuck

Tags: truffle, truffle-contract, truffle-console

I want to exec a script in the truffle console.

## script

```
const artifacts = require('./build/contracts/Message.json')

const contract = require('truffle-contract')
const Message = contract(artifacts);
Message.setProvider(web3.currentProvider);


module.exports = ()=> {
  creator = web3.eth.accounts[0];
  purchaser = web3.eth.accounts[1];
  web3.personal.unlockAccount(creator);
  var messageInstance = null;
  Message.deployed().then(inst => { return messageInstance = inst}).then( () =>{ console.log("Creating Message"); return messageInstance.createMessage(creator, "message.newMessage") }).catch((error)=> { console.error("error", error) }).then( ()=> { return console.log("End");} )
}
```

### Manually

When I manually insert the script (just the part inside module.exports), line by line it works and I get the last `console.log`.

### With exec

When I run exec `./run.js`: the script gets stuck at the second Promise without any error.

Comment: Does it work fine if you set `web3.eth.defaultAccount = web3.eth.accounts[0]` in `truffle develop` beforehand?

Comment: This is not an ethereum issue. It is that javascript is used incorrectly. You assign a function to `module.exports`, and it should be used when you want a function to be used from a another file. If you just want to execute the body of the function then you do not need a function or assigning it to `module.exports`, type the instruction directly in your file.

Comment: @ Ismael, `module.exports`is fine: https://truffleframework.com/docs/truffle/getting-started/writing-external-scripts

Comment: @PaulRBerg setting an unlocking an account (beforehand and in the script) doesn't help. Although I don't know what I change but I get an `Error: invalid address` error when calling the promise chain with exec. Which is usally the error for not having a default acount. I `console.log` the default account and it shows the right one on both solutions (beforehand & in the script).

Comment: I figured it out @PaulRBerg thx for giving me the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution worked:

```
const messageBuild = require('./build/contracts/Message.json')
const contract = require('truffle-contract')
const Message = contract(messageBuild);

module.exports = (callback)=> {
  Message.setProvider(web3.currentProvider);

  var creator = web3.eth.accounts[0]
  var purchaser = web3.eth.accounts[1]

  web3.eth.defaultAccount = creator
  web3.personal.unlockAccount(creator);

  Message.defaults({from: creator})

  var messageInstance = null
  Message.deployed().then(inst => { return messageInstance = inst}).then( () =>{ console.log("Creating Message:", typeof messageInstance.createMessage, "creator", creator, "web3.eth.defaultAccount", web3.eth.defaultAccount); return messageInstance.createMessage(creator, "This is a classic warning") }).catch((error)=> { console.error("\n\n\n\n==>error", error) }).then( () =>{ console.log("Reading Message", typeof messageInstance.readMessage); return messageInstance.readMessage(creator).then((msg) => console.log("The result is:", msg)) }).then( ()=> { return console.log("End"); return callback()} )
}
```

I think it was the missing from:

```
Message.defaults({from: creator})
```

[Truffle invalid address](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/12957/truffle-invalid-address)

Comment: For others: the fix isn't the missing "from", its the addition of a callback parameter, and actually calling it.

Use this as your function template:
```
    module.exports = async function(callback) {
  
      return callback()
    };```

Comment: If you don't call back, the execution never continues, so you get a hang!